# Redirect user to a custom link after login in Django

Tags: python, django, django-login

I have been going through lots of similar questions and solutions from the past couple of days but not able to find a working solution in my case.

My code is :

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/$', login  ,{'template_name': 'login_template.html'}),
    url(r'^dashboard/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', login_required(DashboardHomeViewClass.as_view()),name = "dashboard"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class DashboardHomeViewClass(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):


        device_user_objects = device_user_data.objects.filter(User_Name = request.user.username)
        device_parameter_objects = device_parameter_data.objects.all()

        device_alias_list = []
        device_id_list = []

        queryset = []

        light_list = []


        for device in device_user_objects:
            device_alias_list.append(device.Device_Alias_Data)
            device_id_list.append(device.Device_Id_Data)

        default_device = device_id_list[0]



        slug = self.kwargs.get("slug")

        for device_id in device_id_list:

            if slug == device_id:
                queryset = device_parameter_objects.filter(Device_Id = slug)


        for data_object in queryset:

            light_list.append(data_object.Light)


        recent_light = light_list[-1]   

        context_logged = {'device_user_objects': device_user_objects,
        'light_list': light_list,
        'recent_light': recent_light}


        return render(request, "dashboardhometemplate.html", context_logged)
```

**HTML part in which this context is being used in dashboardhometemplate.html**

```
{%for item in device_user_objects%}
    <li> <a  href="/dashboard/{{item.Device_Id_Data}}" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i><span class="hide-menu">{{item.Device_Alias_Data}}</span></a>
{% endfor %}
```

**Now what I want to do is**

To redirect the user after **login** to the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/{{value of **default_device** variable declared and defined in views.py}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render


def login_view_function(request):
    # ....your code to determine if login allowed or not and populate the 'login_success' variable.

    if login_success:
        return redirect('/your/url_here')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

Comment: This throws a syntax error.I tried with -

`if login_successful:
   return redirect ('/dashboard/some_name')
  else:
   return render (request, 'login_template.html')`

But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the login_view function, after log in don't redirect to "/", redirect to to that function. In your urls.py, you should give a name to the path. Ex: path(..., name=default_device_dashboard). 
redirect("default_device_dashboard")
Ps. Use explicit paths, not implicit ones

Comment: I am totally new to Django, so if you can please explain a bit more. It will be of great help, I am stuck here from past two days.

Comment: I just came across that the login_view which was defined was useless. I've updated the question with removed useless code snippet

Comment: redirect(dashboard slug=device_user_data.slug)